# Eliminate duplicates in array (JSONiq)

Tags: arrays, json, duplicates, zorba, jsoniq

I'd like to delete duplicates in a JSONiq array.

```
let $x := [1, 2, 4 ,3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5]
```

How can I eliminate the duplicates in $x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let $x := [1, 2, 4 ,3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5]
return [ distinct-values($x[]) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [replace function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) multiple times:

```
replace($x, "([1-5])(.*)\1", "$1")
```

Here's a fully functional JavaScript equivalent:

```
[1,2,4,3,3,1,2,5].toString().replace(/([1-5]),(\1)/g, "$1").replace(/(,[1-5])(.*)(\1)/g,"$1$2").replace(/([1-5])(.*)(,\1)/g,"$1$2")
```

Here is a generic JavaScript equivalent via the `JSON.parse()` method, which removes duplicates automatically:

```
var foo = [1,2,4,3,3,1,2,5];

var bar = "{" + foo.toString() + "}"

var baz = bar.replace(/(\d)(.)/g , '\u0022$01\u0022:\u0022\u0022$02')

var bop = JSON.parse(baz)

var buz = JSON.stringify(bop).replace("{","[").replace("}","]").replace(/:""/g,"")

var result = Function("return" + buz)()
```

Here is a test harness:

- [JSONiq Online Tester](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)

Answer (score 0):

regexp:replace is definitely not the way to go for this problem.

While Matthias's solution does not work on Try Zorba, [this script](http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/wLoH23KoUJtG6ipp9dB8TsvBa%2BM%3D) does:

```
let $x := [1, 2, 4 ,3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5]
return [ distinct-values( jn:members($x) ) ]
```

It returns (try out on above link):

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Script needs to be a bit more verbose for [DataPower Gateways](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-datapower-gateways) JSONiq processor. There you get pretty-printed result for free:

```
$ cat dv.xq 
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method "json";
declare option jsoniq-version "0.4.42";

[ distinct-values( jn:members(.) ) ]
$ 
$ coproc2 dv.xq <(echo '[1, 2, 4 ,3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5]') http://dp1-l3:2226; echo

[
  1,
  2,
  4,
  3,
  5
]
$
```

Hermann.